# Program can not login into website

Tags: java, http

This is my code:

```
        URL url = new URL("http://superchillin.com/login2.php");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        String data = "email="+URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8")+"&password="+URLEncoder.encode(pass, "UTF-8");

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,lt;q=0.6");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(data.getBytes().length));
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", "place=1");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", "lvca_unique_user=1");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Host", "superchillin.com");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Origin", "http://superchillin.com");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://superchillin.com/login.php");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36");


        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);


        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(data);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
```

After that code I only read the response. It redirects me to "login.php" and is trying to set cookie "place=1"...

Connecting via browser works great. The reason for so many headers is I thought they may be the problem so I copied all headers from which I see when using a browser.

The response code is 200.

I also noticed that if password or email is incorrect, there's a message saying that in HTML which i retrieve.

When I use a browser I get redirected to index.php and cookie "auth" is set. So that's what I'm expecting from my program aswell. Curently I get redirected back to "login.php".

Comment: This isn't a great question, as it's not clear to us what the specific problem is.  What output do you *expect*?  What output do you *get* (i.e. what are you measuring in order to determine that the login failed)?

Comment: I added more info. I expect to be redirected to index.php and currently I get redirected to login.php. Note I send the request to a file called "login2.php"

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal answer to this question, I'm afraid.  What you're asking is "why does the remote server not return an `auth` cookie when I send this exact request?"  And that depends entirely on what the server's documentation says about those requests, whether it has any bugs in its implementation, etc.

If you don't have access to the server's own source and logs, then you'll likely have to get by with experimentation.  Use something like Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools to capture the exact requests sent by the browser with the login works successfully.  Since these text strings are the only thing the remote server sees, if you replicate them exactly with your Java program you will(/should) get exactly the same responses.

If you think you're sending the same requests from Java and find that you're still not getting the expected responses, there must be some difference.  Try recording the network traffic with something like Wireshark in order to see exactly what your app is sending - and then address the differences.

And if you get to the point where e.g. a redirect isn't being followed, and you're not sure how to do that with a `URLConnection` - then *that's* a good concrete question to ask.

Comment: That's the thing. I am using Google Chromes Developer tools to see and replicate the request. I tried using Wireshack but could didn't find requests to that server